# Multiple file upload Java/servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

Good Morning,

I would like to ask how is it possible to upload multiple files on a single  tag of a form, in particular using Servlet as callback. I already tried all the solutions around the web but none of these seems to work.

Currently, my code is

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Part> fileParts = (List<Part>) request.getParts(); 
    System.out.println(fileParts.size());


    for(Part filePart : fileParts) {
        if (filePart != null && filePart.getSize() > 0) {
            System.out.println(filePart.toString());
        String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); 
            String fileName = filePart.getSubmittedFileName();


            InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
            File uploads = new File("/*the physical path on my machine*/");     

            File file = new File(uploads, fileName);    

            if(file.exists()) {
                Files.deleteIfExists(file.toPath());
            }
            else {
                Files.copy(fileContent, file.toPath());
            }
        }
    }
    //      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    //      boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    //
    //        if (isMultipart) {
    //            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    //            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    //
    //            try {
    //              LinkedList<String> files = new LinkedList<String>();    
    //                List items = upload.parseRequest((RequestContext) request);
    //                Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
    //                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    //                    FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
    //
    //                    if (!item.isFormField()) {
    //                        String fileName = item.getName();
    //                        files.add(fileName);
    //
    //                        String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    //                        File path = new File(root + "/uploads");
    //                        if (!path.exists()) {
    //                            boolean status = path.mkdirs();
    //                        }
    //
    //                        File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);
    //                        System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    //                        item.write(uploadedFile);
    //                    }
    //                }
    //
    //                session.setAttribute("file", files);  
    //                request.setAttribute("uploadOK", true);                       
    //                request.getRequestDispatcher("upload.jsp").forward(request,    response);
    //            } catch (FileUploadException e) {
    //                e.printStackTrace();
    //                request.setAttribute("uploadNO", true);                       
    //                request.getRequestDispatcher("upload.jsp").forward(request, response);
    //            } catch (Exception e) {
    //                e.printStackTrace();
    //                request.setAttribute("uploadNO", true);                       
    //                request.getRequestDispatcher("upload.jsp").forward(request, response);
    //            }
    //        }

}
```

the commented lines are another solution i was trying.

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54734773/175554 may help